# Gradual count in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue with a query. I would like to count column and try to check when result of count will be of some value and in row when value will be I would like to stop count and show date.

Example: I have column A with values (10,5,10,3) and column date with values (1.1.,2.1.,3.1.,4.1.)
and I would like to have for instance when count will be 15 to see in which date it was completely counted with result 15 (10 + 5 = 15 => 2.1.)

Thanks for help.

Tomas

Comment: Can you format your data as tables?  Hint:  You can use the `{}` button to format tables or prepend the row with four spaces.

Comment: sounds like you need a loop and a cursor